# Extract integers from strings

Tags: python, label

I want to create the target list for a clustering problem with numerous classes from the list of the class names (labels) across each instance of my dataset.

```
class_name = ['class_1','class_2','class_3','class_3','class_1','class_2',\
'class_2','class_1','class_1','class_2','class_1','class_3']
```

The target list should be like an array in the same length as the class_name list, where an integer is assigned to different class label. Which is the bets way to get this?

```
target = np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3])
```

A class label (e.g. class_1) is in the form 'Xx_xx_xxx(A123)' or 'Xx_xx_xxx (A123)'. The text in the parenthesis is not fixed. The list type is *'unicode'*.

Comment: Uhm, what? So the class names have another format than the strings in your example? Please provide a complete example with actually valid classnames such that we can adjust our answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that you should do is get the classes in a standard format.  From what you described above, if the classname is in the parens within the string, then you can use a regex to just get the classname.

```
import re
X = ['abc(class_1)', 'cde_(class_1)', 'def_(class_2)']
just_classes = [re.findall(r'\((.*)\)', thing)[0] for thing in X]
# ['class_1', 'class_1', 'class_2']
```

There are a few different approaches you can use here.  If you're doing ml with the numpy, scipy stack, I'd suggest learning the sklearn library.  It has a lot of useful machine learning and AI tools including encoding class names.

## Using sklearn

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
class_names = ['class_1','class_2','class_3','class_3','class_1','class_2',\
        'class_2','class_1','class_1','class_2','class_1','class_3'] 

my_enc = LabelEncoder()
my_enc.fit(class_names)
encoded1 =  my_enc.transform(class_names)
```

## No external library

```
classes = set(class_names)
d = {c:i for i,c in enumerate(classes)}
encoded2 = [d[c_name] for c_name in class_names]
print encoded1 #approach 1 gives numpy array
print encoded2 # approach 2 gives standard python list
```

Both of the approaches should work.  It's not much code to implement on your own, but in general, I'd suggest looking at the sklearn [preprocessing](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to `split` the strings on `'_'` characters, take the digit at index `[1]`, then convert to `int`

```
>>> target = np.array([int(i.split('_')[1]) for i in class_name])
>>> target
array([1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3])
```